# Bound output values

Tags: machine-learning

Here is an open question:

suppose I need to predict a student's exam score given some inputs, e.g. hours spent on prep, previous scores, etc. How should I bound the output between 0 - 100? What are the best practices out there?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Since the answers are mostly concerned about bounding model output after we have the predictions, is it possible to train the model beforehand such that this bound is implicitly learned by the model?

Answer (score 1):

You would train an Isotonic Regression model: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.isotonic.IsotonicRegression.html

Or you could simply clip the predicted values that are out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up isotonic regression.

Answer (score 0):

It is general practice, when training multi-flavored data to appropriately scale it between 0 - 1, so for example, say ur test data was:

[input: [10 hrs studying, 100% on last test], output: [95% on this test] ]

then you should first standardize both input and output by dividing by the greatest numerical value in each of their elements or the greatest possible value:

input = input/input.max

output = output/100

[input: [0.1 , 1], output: [0.95] ]

When you are done training and want to predict a test scores, simply multiply the output by 100 and you are done.

BTW what you want to do is well documented on stephenwelch's Neural Network Youtube series.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do Normalisation or Standardisation. They would transform your values within [0, 1].

I am not sure why you need the range to be 0-100, but if it is really so, you can multiply by 100 to get that range post the above transformation.

**Normalise**: Here each value of your feature column is converted like so:

X_new = (X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min)

where X_min and X_max are min and max values in the feature.

**Standardise**: Here each value of your feature column is converted like so:

X_new = (X - Mean) / StandardDeviation

where Mean and StandardDeviation are the mean and SD values of your feature.

Check which one gives you better results. If your data has extreme outliers, Standardisation might give better results.

In sklearn, you can use sklearn.preprocessing.normalize or sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler to do the conversions.

HTH